# how does the firefox encoding the url in the address bar

Tags: javascript, firefox, encoding

When I use the firefox,I found that it will encoding the Chinese characters in the address bar,which make it difficult for decode .

Exemaple:

In the js code,I have encoding the url:

```
location.href="http://xxx/query.html?type="+encodingURI('中文');
```

Then in the address bar,the firefox show me this:

```
http://xxx/query.html?type=中文
```

but,if I enter the "Enter" key in the address,which means reload this page,then the address will be changed to

```
http://xxx/query.html?type=%D6%D0%CE%C4
```

Then I can not decode the "=%D6%D0%CE%C4". Since it can not be decoded using

```
decodeURI('%D6%D0%CE%C4');
```

In fact the `encodeURI("中文")="%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87"`

I wonder how does firefox do and how to decode the parameter?

Comment: It a known Firefox bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552273

Comment: I see it,any way to resolove it? since we encounter this in the firefox 3.6,while it does not occur in firefox 5+,but we can not make our visitor to update to 6.

Comment: @c69: I disagree. The behavior described in this question simply doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @user954921: `%D6%D0%CE%C4` is GB2312 encoding. Firefox wouldn't simply change the encoding from UTF-8 to GB2312. Just to be certain I verified it in Firefox 3.6 on a webpage using GB2312 encoding - pressing Enter in the location bar doesn't change anything. You might want to check your extensions, maybe one of them is doing this. Btw, the page is reloaded by clicking the Reload button and that's what 99.9% of the users will do ;)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox doesn't behave that way for me. It's not encoding those characters in the URL when I hit enter.

By the way, the correct UTF-8 encoding of `中文` is `%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87`.

```
encodeURIComponent("中文");
"%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87"

decodeURIComponent("%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87");
"中文"
```

For example: [http://google.com?q=中文](http://google.com?q=%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87).

Comment: the function you mention is the correct one to decode Firefox URLs

Answer (score 0):

It's using standard url encoding, you need to make sure you have the correct doctype to display those characters, otherwise you will get unsatisfactory results.